# Short text fall into a second line on one device

Tags: android, css, react-native, responsive

I've created a slide up menu using the react native modal. There is a strange UI behaviour on Nokia 8.3 5g (Resolution: 1080 x 2400, Android version: 11).

[image]

You can see the last letters of the **Notes** and **Close** text fallen into a second line. This only happens on the device mentioned.

I've extracted some parts of the code and added here (only the menu items related code) :

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modal: {
        margin: 0
    },
    modalWindow: {
         justifyContent: 'flex-end',
         flex: 1

     },
     modalContent: {
         backgroundColor: COLORS.white
     },
     header: {
         height: 58,
         backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
         alignItems: "center",
         justifyContent: "center",
         borderBottomWidth: 1,
         borderBottomColor: COLORS.grayLight     
     },
     headerText: {
         color: COLORS.black,
         fontFamily: FONTFAMILY.bold,
         justifyContent: 'center',
         fontSize: FONTSIZE.md,
         letterSpacing: .16,
         lineHeight: 19
     },
     footer: {
         height: 94,
         backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
         paddingBottom: 32,
         paddingTop: 16,
         paddingHorizontal: 16,
     },
     listSection: {
         maxHeight: (SCREEN_HEIGHT/5) * 3
     },
     listItem: {
         height: 48,
         paddingLeft: 16,
         borderBottomWidth: 1,
         borderBottomColor: COLORS.grayLight
     },
     itemContainer: {
         justifyContent: 'flex-start',
         flex: 1, 
         flexDirection: 'row', 
         alignItems: 'center',
     },
     menuItemText: {
         fontFamily: FONTFAMILY.regular,
         fontSize: FONTSIZE.md,
         letterSpacing: .16,
         lineHeight: 19,
         marginLeft: 10
     }
 });

<Modal ...>
    ...
    <View style={styles.listSection}>
         <FlatList
              data={this.getMenuItems()}
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderRow(item)}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
         />
     </View>
</Moda>

renderRow = (item: SlideUpMenuItem) => {
    return <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.listItem]}
        onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
                isModalVisible: false,
                clickEvent: item.onClick.bind(undefined, item)
            });
        }}
    >
        <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
            {item.icon}
            <Text style={styles.menuItemText}>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>;
}

const getMenuItems = () => {
    return [
        {
            id: 1,
            icon: <Start />,
            name: 'Start Job', 
            isVisible: true,
            onClick: props.onStart
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            icon: <Stop />,
            name: 'End Job', 
            isVisible: props.shouldShowStartStop && props.inProgress,
            onClick: props.onStop
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            icon: <Photos />,
            name: 'Attachments', 
            isVisible: props.shouldShowPhots,
            onClick: props.onPhotos
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            icon: <History />,
            name: 'History', 
            isVisible: true,
            onClick: props.onHistory
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            icon: <Notes />,
            name: 'Notes', 
            isVisible: props.shouldShowNotes,
            onClick: props.onNotes
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: Try removing or adjusting `letterSpacing` and `lineHeight` in `menuItemText` style. It might be device specific issue of fonts style

Answer (score 1):

Try removing or adjusting `letterSpacing` and `lineHeight` in `menuItemText` style. It might be device specific issue of fonts style

```
menuItemText: {
  ....
  letterSpacing: .16, // remove this
  lineHeight: 19, // remove this
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the device to check. I tried setting up an emulator with the same spec and couldn't reproduce..  But I tried changing these 2 styles and to reproduce this in my device. That didn't work either..

If this is a style issue, shouldn't the same problem be there for the other menu items? Why only the Notes effected here?